# Restructuring Pandas Dataframe for large number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which is a large number of answers given by users in response to a survey and I need to re-structure it. There are up to 105 questions asked each year, but I only need maybe 20 of them.

The current structure is as below.

[image]

What I want to do is re-structure it so that the row values become column names and the answer given by the user is then the value in that column. In a picture (from Excel), what I want is the below (I know I'll need to re-name my columns, but that's fine once I can create the structure in the first place):
[image]

Is it possible to re-structure my dataframe this way? The outcome of this is to use some predictive analytics to predict a target variable, so I need to re-strcture before I can use Random Forest, kNN, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want try pivoting your table:

```
df.pivot(index=['SurveyID', 'UserID'], columns=['QuestionID'], values=['AnswerText'])
df.columns = [x[0] if x[1] == "" else "Answer_{}".format(x[1]) for x in df.columns.to_flat_index()]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I'm going to mark this as a solution. The only issue it leaves me with is a sort of 2-level column name (e.g. I have AnswerText and then a 1 in the box below it). Is it possible to combine these?

Comment: @user6074035: see added new line in answer above